# How to centralize database models folder if it is use in multiple projects?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sequelize.js, bitbucket

We have 3 different **RESTapis** namely A,B and C and all access the same `MySQL` database.
Our stack is `NodeJS + ExpressJS + SequlizeJS ORM + MySQL`

Right now if I want to create a new db model, I need to create it in the api A and
communicate with other developers who are working on the api B and C to copy and paste new model in their projects' models folder.

This is **very inefficient** and has many mistakes during the process.

So instead of doing this manually, can we automate this task with a new repo in the bitBucket?
The idea is to create a repo in bitBucket and some how refer that models folder in all 3 projects instead of keeping models folder in each and every project?

How do I achieve this using NodeJS, ExpressJS and BitBucket?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that by API A, B and C you are referring to completely different projects here. If that's the case then i can suggest you to use GIT Submodules. But having extensively used submodules i would suggest to use this only if it is inevitable.

Project Structure That i usually work on:

```
.(Git Root)
├── logs
├── resources
├── schema
│   └── <different-entities>
├── src
│   ├── config
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── jobs
│   │   ├── emails
│   │   └── notifications
│   ├── locales
│   ├── middlewares
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models (You need to have a git submodule here)
│   ├── public
│   ├── seeders
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── entities
│   │   └── factories
│   ├── transformers
│   ├── types
│   ├── types-override
│   ├── util
│   └── validators
│       ├── keywords
│       └── <different-entities>
├── storage
│   ├── <date>
├── stubs
└── temp_files
```

This sounds easy but keep these things in mind:

- If your existing project has `models` directory in git history, you cannot create a submodule on that directory (At least not an easy way. The way i did it was rename `models` to `shared-models`)
- Now there will be 2 git repositories:

  **A.** git repository containing all the model files (You will never open this GIT repo. in your IDE)

  **B.** the main git repository of your project.

  So there will be unnecessary merge conflicts most of the time you
  merge any branches in your main repository. because main repository just keeps track of commit hash your models repository should be on at that moment. Any new commit (Irrespective of whether it's even fast-forward will be treated as a merge conflict)

[image: This is how it looks on bitbucket. I've obfuscated name of services repository and partially obfuscated hash of commit of services repository the main project is referencing...]

- Third and the drawback that's most tiring: Suppose you have to just make a change in model file and nothing else in project changes. (Yes, that's infrequent but possible. e.g. adding another enum value in status key). To achieve this you will have to make two commits, first one in models repository which will store the actual changes, then in the main repository which will store the new commit hash and push two commits on two different repositories

If I have not lost you already & you feel this is the right approach for your use case (I can't think of anything better though)

1. copy your complete models directory to a new place (Let's say desktop).
2. git init inside ~/Desktop/models
3. push it on a separate bitbucket repo. (I usually name it `<project>-models-<lang>`, e.g. `facebook-models-node`)
4. come back to your main Project A.
5. remove models directory there
6. run: `git submodule add <HTTPS/SSH Url of bitbucket> src/shared-models`
7. replace imports of models from `src/models` to `src/shared-models`
8. Repeat steps 5-7 for other projects too

Official GIT Submodule: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: I forgot to mention, The submodules work like a charm in Webstorm.. You just need to open the main project.. More details about submodules here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules